# Ideal selector for Cypress automation Javascript

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, cypress

I have this HTML code

```
<li class="menu-level-1">

    <a href="/Public/app/#/calendar">
        <i class="site-menu-icon material-icons">date_range</i>
        <span>
            Calendar
        </span>

    </a>
</li>
```

I don't know exactly what I need to select in CYPRESS for automation to press the calendar button. I don't have a unique css or id class so I can't isolate it from the rest of the menu items. I only have what is seen in this code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to click the element `<a href="/Public/app/#/calendar">` since it has the `href`.

There's lots of ways to target it, the one to use depends on what is unique on the page

```js
cy.contains('a', 'Calendar').click()  // if the word Calendar only appears on this link
```

```js
cy.get('a[href="/Public/app/#/calendar"]').click()  // specifies by the link itself
```

```js
cy,get('i.site-menu-icon').parent().click()  // if the icon is the unique thing
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom xpath like `//*[text()="Calendar"]`

If you have found many others on your web page, you can give an index like `//*[text()="Calendar"][1]` make sure here the index always starts with 1, not 0.

Comment: I have this error: "Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: //*[text()="Calendar"][1], but never found it."

Comment: have you tried `//*[text()="Calendar"]`. I have given you just a hint you need to pass an index that matches the element correctly.

Comment: Yes, I tried in several ways with xpath after installing it with npm and importing but every time I have the same error. i used the statement: cy.xpath('code').click()

Comment: can you send me all the details so I run them on my system?